# How do I remove repeated pattern except the last one with Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Good day,

I would like to know if that's possible using **RegExp** and if so, how.

Here is the problem:

In a string, I have multiple pattern that correspond to colors:

```
{r for dark red
{R for bright red
{G for bright green
{W for white
{* for black
... and so on...
```

Sometimes the data I'm parsing contains lot of useless color changes
Example:

`{r{Gthis text is finally green`

The `{r` is totally useless there. It wouldn't if the string was `{rSomething {Gthis text is finally green`

I would like a way to match every `{<color references>` that is right before any other `{<color references>` and leaves the last one in place.

`{r{Gthis text is green` -> `{Gthis text is green`
`That text is {R{rdark red` -> `That text is {rdark red`

Is that an easy way to do that?

I am aware that this problem is really particular and will probably never help anyone else.

But help would be really appreciate.

Thank you!

PS: The codes is used in **Javascript** so if possible, I would like a solution working in Javascript.

**Edit:**

I must be able to do `{Y{r{Gthis te{*xt {Y{yis green` and get `{Gthis te{*xt {yis green`

Comment: What have you tried (in other words, post the Javascript that you have thus far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method that works.  It works like this:

1. Search for one or more color codes follow by another color code.
2. A color code is considered a `{` followed by any other single character except a `{`.  If there are only a specified set of color codes that you want to allow or there are more characters that are not allowable color codes, then those could also be added to the regex, but you didn't specify that additional info.
3. The regex for a single color code is this: `\{[^\{]`. This is a `{` followed by any single character that is not a `{`.  If you want it to only be alpha characters, it could be changed to this: `\{[a-zA-Z]`.
4. Replace the multiple consecutive color codes with the last color code using the sub-matches from the match.
5. This technique will remove all but the last color code even when there are more than two color codes in a row.
6. This technique will not remove things that don't look like valid color codes like `{{`.

This works for any character in the color code since you looked like you had a long list of valid single character codes.  But, it protects against {{ which it will not treat as a color code.

```
var str = "{r{G{ythis text is finally green";
var result = str.replace(/(\{[^\{])+(\{[^\{])/g, "$2");
```

or to allow just alpha characters to be a color code character, it would be this:

```
var result = str.replace(/(\{[a-zA-Z])+(\{[a-zA-Z])/g, "$2");
```

You can see a test fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jNXUz/

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = "{r{Gthis text is green".replace(/^{(.+){/, '{');
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: This almost works. But a part of the string is removed when using: `{Y{r{Gthis te{*xt {Y{yis green` -­> `{yis green`

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I'd use a regex like `([\{a-zA-Z]{2})([{A-Za-z\ ]+)` you would then strip out group 1, or just extract group 2.

The regex I've given isn't as concise as it could be, but thats up to you to make better and more particular to your needs. Try using something like regex buddy to help with further development.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to allow `{` in your strings as well if it's not followed by one of your special characters:

```
var patts = ['\\{r', 
             '\\{R', 
             '\\{G',
             '\\{W',
             '\\{\\*'];
var str = '{r{GThis is a green string';
var patt = '(?:'+patts.join('|')+')';
str = str.replace(new RegExp(patt+'('+patt+')', 'g'), '$1');
// str === "{GThis is a green string"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could search for where one colour code is immediately followed by another one, and remove the first as in the following code:

```
// if you want to list out all possible codes
"{r{Gthis text is finally green".replace(/{[rRGW\*]{/g,"{");

// if you want a generic any character after bracket match
"{r{Gthis text is finally green".replace(/{.{/g,"{");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like so: http://jsfiddle.net/BdWt5/

```
var patterns = {
  r:function(a){
    // dark red implementation
    return '<span style=color:red>'+a+'</span>';
  },
  G:function(a){
    // green implementation
    return '<span style=color:green>'+a+'</span>';
  }
};

var str = '{rTesting{GTesting}}',match;

while(match = str.match(/{([^{}]+)}/)){
  str=str.replace(match[0],patterns[match[1].slice(0,1)](match[1].slice(1)))
}
```